# How to set ng-click in angularJS Controller (IONIC)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, ionic-framework, leaflet

I have a problem adding a function-call to html in the AngularJS Controller.

UPDATE:
Okay I have to be a little bit more concrete:

My Problem is about a leaflet popup with a button inside.
The geojson data loads asynchronous and I have a "onEachFeature" function to add the popup - the function looks like: (IT'S SIMPLIFIED!)

```
.controller('MapCtrl', function($scope, $state) {
  function oef(feature, layer) {
    var bounds = layer.getBounds();
    var center = bounds.getCenter();

    var marker = L.marker(center).addTo(MAP);

    var popup = new L.Popup({
        autoPan: false,
        keepInView: true,
        closeButton: false,
        offset: new L.point(0, -5)
     }).setContent("<div><a ng-click='test()'>"+feature.properties.tooltip + "</a></div>");


   }

   //LOADING AND ADDING DATA TO MAP
   ....
   //END

   $scope.test = function(){
     alert("HI");
   }
});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Why do you have HTML code inside your controller and not the view?

Comment: I changed my code above - so now it should be a little bit more understandable

Comment: @nrhode didn't you get it working with the Angular's `$compile'`?

Comment: No, the problem is, that the popup get initialized on the click event on the map. So I need to compile after calling the popup. That wan't work...
But yes, for "normal" cases your code works well!

Answer (score 2):

You need to compile your html in order to allow angular to interpret "the angular code" in the html (See https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile), otherwise it's just a simple string in the "angular world". See the sample listed below.

```js
angular.module('myapp', [])
  .controller('foo', function($scope, $compile) {

    var div = "<div><a ng-click='hello()'>Hi</a>";
    var parent = angular.element(document.querySelector('#target')).append(div)
    $compile(parent.contents())($scope);

    $scope.hello = function() {
      console.log("'Hi div' clicked: Hi!")
    }
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
  .hand {
    cursor: hand;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
</style>

<div ng-app="myapp">

  <div ng-controller="foo">
    <div id="target" class="hand"></div>
  </div>

</div>
```